# Is there a price list for goods outside of the core book?

Tags: equipment, pricing, l5r, l5r-4e

Rokugan is a very varied place, and characters might want to acquire a lot of things that are not covered in the core book.

Like, recently I came into the pickle that a painting samurai wanted to acquire a set of fancy Sumi-e colors and use those to justify a higher base TN for a picture he was painting. That's a fair idea - a higher base material means a higher base value, which in turn determines the TN according to the rules. The closest the miscellaneous equipment list offers to paint however is a *bottle of fabric or hair dye*, and a *writing box*. The latter does actually say in its description that it contains the material for Sumi-e, so the price was tripled to reflect the more fancy inks and paint inside.

While such extrapolating often helps a lot, there are massive gaps in what miscellaneous things or items that listed, excluding quite a few things that Samurai justifiably might wish to have as their personal property and not as things given by their lords. Like, what's the *fair price* that a samurai should give to have a falconer's glove made, so he can engage in this very samurai pasttime?<sup>1</sup> How much does the new saddle for the Battle Maiden set back the samurai who wishes to win her heart? How much would a Kaiu Engineer need to have a smith paid to get new tools for his workshop beyond what he needs for his service? Those are questions not really touched upon in the list.

**So, is there a list of miscellaneous items and/or clothing outside of the core rulebook?**

---

<sup>1 - One should not be negligent in the way of the retainer. One should rise at four in the morning, practice sword technique, eat one’s meal, and train with the bow, the gun, and the horse. For a well developed retainer, he should become even more so. If one should want diversions, he should make them such outdoor pastimes such as falconing, deer hunting and wrestling. - Kato Kiyomasa</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 4th Ed

There are certain items that are not in the core book, and only come with the supplements, but they don't fit the *Miscellaneous Equipment* category. All non-magical equipment I could find is this:

- *Book of Earth* delivers armor types<sup>1</sup>
- *Imperial Histories* delivers gaijin pepper and weaponry<sup>2</sup>, bombs<sup>3</sup>
- *Imperial Histories II* brings also gaijin pepper weaponry<sup>4</sup> and special magic items<sup>5</sup> as well as more modern weapons<sup>6</sup>
- *Enemites of the Empire* brings Naga weaponry and items<sup>7</sup>
- *Imperial Archives* gives a couple of non-standard weapons<sup>8</sup>
- *Emerald Empire* gives localized Prices, but no new goods.<sup>9</sup>
- The Houserule gathering *Little Truths* contains only some weapons<sup>10</sup>

All other equipment in the mentioned books and the Book of [element] series is magical in nature. As a result, **there are no other miscellaneous equipment lists in other books for 4th edition.**

---

1 - The Book of Earth, p.26
2 - Imperial Histories, p.95
3 - Imperial Histories, p.180
4 - Imperial Histories 2, p.80
5 - Imperial Histories 2, p.220
6 - Imperial Histories 2, p.307
7 - Enemies of the Empire, p.86
8 - Imperial Archives, p.98
9 - Emerald Empire, p.144
10 - Little Truths, p.22